# Flash CS3 -- tahoma text loading differently than on client's computer

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, flash-cs3

A client has sent me a Flash CS3 website template she was working on. I'm supposed to do some work on it. When I load it, it displays incorrectly. The body type appears incorrectly. It's different then what it appears on her computer. Causing all the body text to overlap each other.

1. She has Windows Vista with Flash CS3. I'm using Windows XP Professional with Flash CS4.
2. When I open the file, it says that 'tahoma' font is missing on my computer. And asks me to select a replacement. Obviously, I have Tahoma on my computer -- everyone does. I even got her to send her version of Tahoma to me from her Windows Font Folder. When I tried to install it, it says "font already installed". So, I pointed it to my Tahoma font as a replacement. This could be the problem. But why does it not recognize my version of tahoma?

Anyone know what's going on, or how I can fix it? I'm supposed to be working on this website, but can't proceed because I might be wasting time if it doesn't match up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried embedding the fonts when exporting the .swf? I don't know if  it'll fix the positioning issues, but it'll fix the text appearance.

Comment: The prob. is I'm supposed to work on this flash file, send it back to the original person, and they're going to work on it some more. But when we send it between each other, it appears differently on our systems because of the font. So we will keep experiencing alignment issues.

Comment: Well,you could ask the person for a swf file,to see if it looks different on your machine, or if possible you could use CS3 to see if it's it's a version compatibility issue. Or even trying different screen resolutions.

Comment: Good stuff. I just asked them for an swf file.

Comment: Great. Post the results here, cause i'm curious, haha. :)

Comment: Ok, here's what was happening. When opening the file in FLASH CS4, it kept making all the tahoma text bold. I installed Flash CS3 trial and turned of all the bold from the tahoma text, it was back to normal. Saved that file. When I tried to open it in FLASH CS4, it added all the bold again. So I'm now finishing the website in FLASH CS3.